# Active menu Issue with sections height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following set-up works fine as long as the content in each section doesn't exceed the section height. When it does, as you can see in the example, the content falls out of the containing section.

Addressing the issue by adding "display: table" or "overflow: hidden" to the section solves this problem but messes the active state behaviour of the menu.

I also tried setting sections height to auto instead of 100% but that messes up the entire layout as sections start overlapping each other.

I'm in desperate need of help as the the entire layout of this project depends on getting this right.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/q2a5ermL/3/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="link active" href="#section_one">Section One</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#section_two">Section Two</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#section_three">Section Three</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#section_four">Section Four</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<section id="section_one"></section>

<section id="section_two">

<div class="row">

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-last"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-last"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-left"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

    <div class="column-last"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/twitter.png"><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.<p></div>

</div>

</section>

<section id="section_three"></section>
<section id="section_four"></section>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px none;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box
}

 html, body {
    height: 100%
}

header {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a.active {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

section {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#section_one {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}

#section_two {
    background: #999999;
}

#section_three {
    background: #777777;
}

#section_four {
    background: #999999;
}

.row {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1600px;
}

.column-left { float: left; width: 25%; }
.column-last { float: right; width: 25%; }

.row p {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

.row img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//-------- Script has negative scrolling of 40px for Header compensation --------:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.link').each(function (event) {
            if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40) {
                $('.link').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    });
});

//------- This part adds smooth scrolling --------:

$(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 40)
                }, 850);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use the CSS way to fix the floats without editing the markup.

```
section:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your time and effort, I've tried your approach but it still messes up the menu. You can try it yourself; You'll notice that the menu links no longer change to active state properly. That is the whole problem...

Comment: Hi there, if you click the third and fourth links you'll see they don't change unless you use the mouse-wheel and after that, if you click number two, number one becomes active instead. I've been trying to solve this for two days now...

Comment: @DavidMartins try a bigger number i.e. `(y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 45)` or smaller one.

Comment: A bigger number in the Offset as you suggested did the trick. You're the best. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clear your floats. If you add this:

```
<br style="clear: both" />
```

At the end of your section it will work: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TempFever/q2a5ermL/4/)

---

Both this and the original fiddle in the question weren't working properly in IE. I changed '40' to '39' on this line and it fixed the issue in IE:

```
scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 39)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, but as you can see in your example, after doing that, the menu links no longer change to active state properly. That is the whole problem...

Comment: Are you not seeing the menu links change to black and become underlined? What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi there, Good point as to which browsers... It works in all of them except Firefox and IE. If you click the third and fourth links you'll see they don't change unless you use the mouse-wheel and after that, if you click number two, number one becomes active instead. I've been trying to solve this for two days now...

Comment: Prior to my edit, I was seeing it work properly in Firefox (version 36) and Chrome (version 42). Both it and your fiddle had the error in IE10. The fixed worked in all three browsers and in IE10 running in IE9 mode. (JSFiddle itself broke when I tried to run it in IE8 mode)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It turns out, playing with the Offset after adding "clear: both", solved the issue. Best wishes.